# Pulsar Spring Boot Cannot get DNS TTL settings from sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy

Tags: apache-pulsar, spring-pulsar

I am trying to initialize PulsarClient in spring-boot's configuration class using the following code but getting

Java Details:

```xml
 <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
        <pulsar.version>3.0.0</pulsar.version>
        <spring.boot.version>3.1.0</spring.boot.version>
 </properties>
```

```java
@Configuration
public class PulsarConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PulsarClient pulsarClient() throws PulsarClientException {
        return PulsarClient.builder().serviceUrl("pulsar://localhost:6650").build();
    }
}
```

#Error:

```
Cannot get DNS TTL settings from sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy class

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.pulsar.common.util.netty.DnsResolverUtil cannot access class sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net to unnamed module @6069db50
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:394) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:709) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.netty.DnsResolverUtil.<clinit>(DnsResolverUtil.java:46) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool.createAddressResolver(ConnectionPool.java:159) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool.lambda$new$1(ConnectionPool.java:126) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:126) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:95) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:90) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarClientImpl.<init>(PulsarClientImpl.java:196) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarClientImpl.<init>(PulsarClientImpl.java:153) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ClientBuilderImpl.build(ClientBuilderImpl.java:63) ~[pulsar-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at in.silentsudo.springbootmongodbdatagenerator.PulsarConfiguration.pulsarClient(PulsarConfiguration.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
```

#Ref:
Found a thread here https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/20282, but I do not wish to downgrade, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unavoidable as of JDK17 and the only way I know to get rid of the warning is to `add-opens` at JVM launch time. By the time we are in the Java client there is nothing that can be done (see [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html#GUID-12F945EB-71D6-46AF-8C3D-D354FD0B1781) for more info on `add-opens`). As such, the only "downgrade" would be to go back to a lower JDK **OR** set the `add-opens` at JVM launch time. Here is an example of where we set it in [spring-pulsar](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-pulsar/commit/cd8adafa079cfdfc9aa6a523d68db0906b22da83).

**TIP:** It looks like you are constructing the client yourself. I am not sure if you are using `spring-pulsar` or not, but when using `spring-pulsar` and `spring-boot`, the client is [automatically configured for you](https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#pulsar-client).

Comment: Yes adding to the launch tp program argument is the only way seems :/

Comment: No luck, so this is the answer. For me.

Comment: I was not using spring-pulsar as i was following bookish example from pulsar in action and triggering producer using rest controller, auto-configuration comes with lot of magic whihc i wanted to avoid

Comment: @onobc it's not that this is "unavoidable as of JDK17". Saying it's unavoidable makes the assumption that the offending library cannot be updated to not use java internals. Pressure should be applied, or help provided, to the library that uses java internals.

Comment: I agree w/ that @axiopisty - good point.